# Snakemake collecting output of previous rule for input of a second rule

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I am trying to run a workflow that will run on a series of .fastq files, merge any files in the same folder, then perform downstream analysis on the merged files. So far, I am able to merge the files, but I cannot get the downstream analysis to run without running snakemake a second time through. I am 99% positive this is because the outputs of the merging rule are not "picked up" by snakemake (and the downstream rules) until snakemake is ran a second time. The relevant rules are as follows:

```py
def get_barcode_folders(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.basecall_barcode.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    barcodes = set()
    for folder in os.listdir(checkpoint_output):
        full_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_output, folder)
        if Path(full_path).is_dir():
            barcodes.add(folder)

    merge_files = [config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/" + barcode + ".merged.fastq" for barcode in barcodes]
    return merge_files

FAST5_FILES = glob_wildcards(config['results_folder'] + "DataFiles/fast5/{fast5_file}.fast5").fast5_file

rule all:
    input:
        # basecall, barcode, and merge files
        get_barcode_folders,

        # nanoQC pre trim
        expand(config['results_folder'] + "NanoQC/Pre-Trim/{barcode}",
               barcode=set(glob_wildcards(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{barcode}.merged.fastq").barcode))


checkpoint basecall_barcode:
    input:
        config['results_folder'] + "DataFiles/fast5/"
    output:
        directory(config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput/")
    conda:
        "envs/pythonEnv.yaml"
    shell:
        r"""
        echo {input}
        """

def merge_files_input(wildcards):
    return glob.glob(config['results_folder'] + f".barcodeTempOutput/{wildcards.barcode}/*.fastq")
rule merge_files:
    input:
        merge_files_input          
    output:
        config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{barcode}.merged.fastq"
    shell:
        r"""
            # merging files in here, works as expected. Touch used as placeholder
            touch {output}
        """

# This rule (and all subsequent rules) I am having problems with
rule NanoQCPreTrim:
    input:
        rules.merge_files.output[0]
    output:
        directory(config['results_folder'] + "NanoQC/Pre-Trim/{barcode}")
    shell:
        r"""
        mkdir {output}
        # Perform NanoQC analysis. mkdir used as placeholder again
        """
```

When I run this on a "clean" run-through (i.e. only some initial .fast5 files are present), the only rules that execute are `basecall_barcode` and `merge_files`. On the first run, `merge_files` is not mentioned by snakemake as it must re-evaluate the output to determine what must be ran, which makes sense to me. However, I do not get `NanoQCPreTrim` to work until I run the workflow a second time, which is what is confusing me very much.

I think this is because there is no data located at `config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{barcode}.merged.fastq"` under `rule all` when the workflow is ran the first time, and as a result, none of the downstream rules (past merge_files) have a need to be ran, because no input is present.

However, I was under the impression that when using snakemake, it will attempt to find necessary input for the output of each rule, and as a result, even though the input files for `rule NanoQCPreTrim` are not currently present, it will run the rule because its outputs are not present, and then work backwards attempting to determine what rules can make its input?

In addition, I thought using checkpoints would also alleviate this problem as the DAG is re-evaluated after `checkpoint basecall_barcode` is complete. As a result, downstream rules would be able to create the necessary input/output based on the now-present files.

I am missing something, and it may be simple, but I have been working nearly all day on this and cannot figure out what seems to be a naive problem. I appreciate any help!

#### **EDIT**

When I run the workflow with `-F` to force all rules, everything works as expected; i.e. each rule is stated in the `Job Counts` section of snakemake

Comment: No clue how this works internally, but perhaps the nanoqc pretrim input in rule all is evaluated before requesting the checkpoint. What if you add this input in a function just as get_barcode_folders and first request the checkpoint to be executed?

Comment: This worked! I thought I had done something similar and couldn't get it going, but nonetheless it does now! Thank you very much

Comment: I've spoken a bit too soon. This works to get the whole workflow going, but after deleting an output file and performing a dry-run, I get a result that nothing needs to be done

Comment: Might be related to the way you glob the input. I think the qc needs to use a similar function as the merging one

Comment: Yes, it appears that I had a problem in returning the correct `glob_wildcard` in the functions similar to the one at the top of my code